# jquery recommended way to do ajax navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

jquery recommended way to do ajax navigation

I just tried out this simple jquery ajax code to load all the links in a page in an ajax manner.

```
$('a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        url = $(this).attr('href');
        $('body').fadeTo('slow', 0.2); 
        $('body').load(url, function(data){
            $(this).fadeTo('slow', 1, function(){
                $(this).html(data);
                scroll(0,0);
            });
        });
    });
```

*[The links in the page stick to the current domain and no external links are present]*

The page load works as expected but the scripts for Facebook, LinkedIn, pinterest buttons fail to load.

I think this is not the safest way to do a ajax navigation and I am sure other JS files, inline JavaScripts will cause error.

http://davidwalsh.name has some good ajax navigation work with mootools. I am trying to achieve the same using jquery.

The website loads and executes every script successfully and it is seen that the ajax work is not done to load specific scripts.

Is there any safe way to achieve this, making sure that the ajax loaded page works as normal as it should ??

Answer (score 0):

You should call the function that attaches the script inside the load handler, so it re-attaches all DOM scripts on each load.

F.ex, if you have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#facebook').doFacebook();
    $('#twitter').doTwitter();
});
```

Change it to:

```
var onload = function() {
    $('#facebook').doFacebook();
    $('#twitter').doTwitter();
};
$(document).ready(onload);
```

Then just call `onload` whenever the `body` gets new content.

Inline scripts should execute according to the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

You might also want to read up on how to manipulate browser history and URL using `.pushState`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries

There are decent jQuery plugins that adds this functionality in a cross-browser manner if you google around a bit.